# Supporting html tags in Unity

Tags: php, html, unity-game-engine

I am creating a unity app which will later be built for Android & iOS only in which I will be fetching content from web services. Data in those web services are made available from a back-end panel made in php. In the back-end we have given the user a text editor in which he can enter his text and do some formatting in it like making text bold,underline, change color of the text.

Now the problem I am facing is that the final text generated by the text editor contains some advanced html tags like div and span which are not supported in unity.

In unity to support these html tags I am using TextMeshPro but that too has very limited support for html tags.

So I want to know is there any asset or any other way available to support a much larger set of html tags in unity

Comment: Did you try using `WebGL Templates`? here is the link: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-templates.html

Comment: @VicJordan will this require me to load the content in the form of html files ?

Comment: @VicJordan I am not creating build for webgl . I am creating for Android and iPhone